# Sencha Ext JS 4 framework examples on IIS 7 configured NOT on port 80 doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, iis-7

I downloaded the Ext JS 4 (http://www.sencha.com) and setup a site on IIS 7 in Windows 7.  After installing PHP on Windows 7, I was finally able to get the framework to run (for some of the example controls/widgets).  The root of my website folder in IIS was the root of the framework--the folder where "index.html" lives.

I set up a binding for domain "localhost" on port 80, and it worked:
http://localhost:8888/index.html

I set up a binding for domain "localhost" on port 8888, and it worked:
http://localhost:8888/index.html

I set up a binding for domain 192.168.1.101 (with IP address 192.168.1.101) on port 80, and it worked:
http://192.168.1.101/index.html

I set up a binding for localhost on port 8888, and it worked:
http://192.168.1.101:8888/index.html

Then I made a port exception for port 8888 on my Windows Firewall. I then set up port forwarding in my LinkSys Router configuration (192.168.1.1) under admin mode, to allow my 192.168.1.101 box to serve my site to my external IP address on port 8888. My Internet Service Provider does not allow port 80.

**I then set up a binding for domain [my external IP address] (with IP address [my external IP address]) on port 8888, and it DID NOT WORK. Why is that? How can I fix this?**

=====================================

## 7/24/2011 updates

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding the external IP cannot work, because IIS doesn't know about it. If you do a port forwarding on your router to `192.168.1.101:8888,` bind IIS to this address/port and all should be fine. In some cases, you might need to try this connection from an external address, possibly via VPN, as some routers don't properly handle the case of accessing  the WAN IP from the LAN.

Comment: oh, I see what you mean.. so I had both my external ip and 101 in my site bindings.  But even after removing the external ip in there, it still doesn't work.  Let me post screen shots for you.

Comment: oh, I see my issue.. I had added a new rule to allow a port in my windows firewall for port 8088, not 8888.  I added one called Sencha for 8888.  Now it works.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: I added the external ip into the bindings, and it didn't hurt anything.  But I see that it's pointless to have it in there.